# Can metaclass be any callable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, types, metaclass

To catch your eyes:

## I think the documentation might be wrong!

According to Python 2.7.12 documentation, **3.4.3. Customizing class creation**:

> `__metaclass__` This variable can be **any callable** accepting
>   arguments for name, bases, and dict. Upon class creation, the callable
>   is used instead of the built-in `type()`.
>
> New in version 2.2.

However, [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20160731141718id_/http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/ch02s05.html) argues:

> **Q**: Wow! Can I use any type object as the `__metaclass__`?
>
> **A**: No. It must be a subclass of the type of the base object. ...

So I did an experiment on my own:

```
class metacls(list):    # <--- subclassing list, rather than type
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dict):
        dict['foo'] = 'metacls was here'
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, dict)

class cls(object):
    __metaclass__ = metacls
    pass
```

This gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    class cls(object):
  File "test.py", line 4, in __new__
    return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, dict)
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type.__new__(metacls): metacls is not a subtype of type
```

So is the document really wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, any callable will do. In your case the `type.__new__()` method has a restriction you are violating; this has nothing to do with what you assign to `__metaclass__`.

A function is a callable:

```
def metaclass_function(name, bases, body):
    return type(name, bases, body)
```

This one just returns the result of `type()` (not `type.__new__()`), yet it is *just a callable*. The return value is used *as the class*. You could really return anything:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __metaclass__ = lambda *args: []
...
>>> Foo
[]
```

Here the callable produced a list instance, so `Foo` is bound to a list. Not very useful, but `__metaclass__` is just called to produce *something*, and that something is used directly.

In your example, the first argument to `type.__new__()` is *not a type*, and it is **that call** that fails. `mcs` is bound to `list`, and not a (subclass of) `type`. `type.__new__()` is free to set such restrictions.

Now, because a metaclass is still tied to the class object (`type(ClassObj)` returns it) and it is used when resolving attribute look-ups on the class object (where the attribute is not available in the class MRO), it is usually a *honking good idea* to make it a subclass of `type`, because that gives you the right implementation of things like `__getattribute__`. It is for that reason that `type.__new__()` make a restriction on what can be passed in as the first argument; it is that first argument that `type()` attaches to the class object returned.

Comment: @sunqingyao: no, `bound` means assigned to. The assignment `Foo = []` is executed. A `class` statement is basically treated as a function; the body is executed as if in a function, and all local names are extracted into a dictionary. Then the class object is produced by calling `bodydict.get('__metaclass__', type)` (so either the value of `__metaclass__` or, if missing, `type`) and passing in the class name, the class bases, and the body dictionary. *Whatever is returned* is assigned to the name of the class. Binding is the technical term; other things bind too, like `import` or `for`.

Comment: But by saying "`mcs` is bound to `list`", you seem to mean "`mcs` is an instance of a subclass of `list`".

Comment: @sunqingyao: no, `mcs = list`, not `list()`, because that's what is passed in to`__new__`. See the [`object.__new__()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__); `__new__` is a static method with the current class being passed in as the first argument.

Comment: And since every object is a subclass of `object`, `object.__new__` doesn't make any restriction on its first argument.

Comment: @sunqingyao: `object.__new__` does make restrictions. Just try `object.__new__(dict)` for an example.

Comment: I think I also understand why the first argument of `type.__new__` cannot be `list`: This is because an instance of `list` is not a type, and thus not a class. So the metaclass isn't "meta" then.

Comment: Hmm...because `dict` makes the instances produced by the metaclass no longer types: We cannot subclass or get an instance from an instance of `dict`.

Comment: Let's make a conclusion: Both `type.__new__` and `object.__new__` only accept instances of `type` whose instances are still types(or, classes) as their first argument. Am I right?

Comment: @sunqingyao: not instances, *subclasses* (or 'subtypes' really). See the [`type_new_wrapper()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Objects/typeobject.c#l4777) for the nitty gritty. `type.__new__` requires the first argument to be a subclass of `type`, `object.__new__` of object, but more importantly, the `PyType_Check` must be true which is a fast way to check if something is subclassing `type`.

Comment: I think `PyType_Check` is a fast way to check if something is an **instance** of `type`(to make sure it's a type/class), while `PyType_IsSubtype` checks if something is **subclassing** `type`.

Comment: @sunqingyao: gah, yes, `PyType_Check` tests for instances of `type`, a.k.a. classes.